# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((224, 224, 3) vs (224, 3))

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

I want to duplicate the MRI images in my data set with GAN, but I get such an error, I would be very grateful if you can help me.

```
images = np.load("resized_images.npy")
labels = np.load("data_label.npy")
print(labels.shape)

#images = np.expand_dims(images, axis=3)
labels=to_categorical(labels-1,3)
class Discriminator(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu", input_shape=(224, 224, 1))
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")
        self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="sigmoid")

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        return x

discriminator = Discriminator()
discriminator.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])


class Generator(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu", input_shape=(100,))
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")
        self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        # Reshape işlemini kaldırın
        x = self.dense3(x)
        return x

generator = Generator()
generator.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

for epoch in range(100):
    for batch in range(len(images) // 224):
        batch_images = images[batch * 224:(batch + 1) * 224]
        batch_labels = labels[batch * 224:(batch + 1) * 224]
        discriminator.trainable = True
        generator.trainable = False
        discriminator.train_on_batch(batch_images, batch_labels)

    for batch in range(len(images) // 224):
        batch_noise = tf.random.normal((224, 100))
        batch_labels = tf.zeros((224, 1))
        discriminator.trainable = False
        generator.trainable = True
        generator.train_on_batch(batch_noise, batch_labels)

    labels_c = tf.expand_dims(labels, axis=-1)
    labels_c = tf.reshape(labels_c, (len(labels), 224, 3))

    real_accuracy = discriminator.evaluate(images, labels_c)
    fake_accuracy = discriminator.evaluate(generator.predict(images), tf.zeros((len(images), 1)))
    print("Epoch: {}, Real Accuracy: {}, Fake Accuracy: {}".format(epoch, real_accuracy, fake_accuracy))
```

I want to duplicate the MRI images in my data set with GAN, but I get such an error, I would be very grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Please edit your question to also include the stacktrace.